# Node.js: Sending server response fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, http, response

I am building a node.js server which receives data on a specific port. This works pretty fine, but I'm not able to send a response afterwards.

Server:

```
http.createServer(function(sock) {

    sock.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('DATA: ' + data);
        sock.write(' saved in the DB');
        db.serialize(function(){
            db.run("INSERT INTO Data values('" + data + "')");
        });

    });

}).listen(PORT, HOST);
```

Error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzeHJ.png

Thanks,
Benedikt

Comment: Are you trying to create an http server (that listens for incoming http requests) or are you just listening for incoming socket requests that will use their own format of data?

Comment: The server is listening to all http requests.
I've tried it with Fiddler and with a java program. Same results

Comment: Well, your code doe not look like you're processing http requests, yet that's the type of server you created.  `http.createServer()` calls the function you pass to it with two arguments as in `function(request, response)`.  It does not pass a socket.  You need to use those specific arguments and their methods/properties when you create an http server.

Comment: But in this example it works that way(first code example): http://www.hacksparrow.com/tcp-socket-programming-in-node-js.html

Comment: Yes you are right, i need listen for socket requests. thank you!

Comment: Next time if you actually tell us (in words) what you're trying to accomplish along with your code, then we could have offered you a solution much, much faster.  It looks like you've figured out you want `net.createServer()`, not `http.createServer()`.  I will post this as an answer to you can accept it and finish the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to be using `net.createServer()` instead:

```
var net = require('net');

net.createServer(function(sock) {
    // code here that uses the socket
});
```